# Using two models on the same Admin page

Tags: python, django

I'd been searching two days how to make it, and the other question I found are not my problem.
I have 3 models:

```
class ProductBase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50) # and some code
class Serie(models.Model):
    #some specific fields
    productbase = models.OneToOneField(ProductBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Movie(models.Model):
    #some specific fields
    productbase = models.OneToOneField(ProductBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The Admin shows me a Create/Edit Form for the ProductBase Model, one for the Serie Model, and one for the Movie Model. But I want to show a Create/Edit Form for Serie/ProductBase Model, and one for Movie/ProductBase Model, so creating a serie, I create a ProductBase and a Serie Model, and a relations between them. I thoght using Inlines but, that's for de ProductBase and I can't regsiter the ProductBAse two times with different AdminModels and Inlines.
The other way is breaking the ProductBase in the two models Serie and Movie, but that is a bad design.
Thanks for your help
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think abstract models is what you are looking for.

For example:

```
class AbstractProductBase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Serie(AbstractProductBase):
     # some specific fields


class Movie(AbstractProductBase):
    # some specific fields
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes